# Disable conversion to UTC timezone after deserialization of a response from Invoke-Restmethod

Tags: powershell, datetime-format

I'm using the Invoke-RestMethod to get the data from REST API. One of the attributes in response is the date. When using Postman or other tools to get the data the date is returned correctly but when I'm using PowerShell (version 5.1.19041.906) and its Invoke-RestMethod like this:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $requestHeaders
```

All values from the date attribute are automatically converted to UTC. Is there any way how to disable this shift? I need the original values returned from the API.

Comment: All values returned by `Invoke-RestMethod` have _already been deserialized_ for you. If you want the raw JSON response, use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod), when given a JSON response, automatically parses it into a `[pscustomobject]` graph; in a manner of speaking, it has [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) *built in*.

When `ConvertFrom-Json` does recognize what are invariably *string* representation of dates in the input JSON, it converts them to `[datetime]` instances.

**In *Windows PowerShell* (v5.1, the latest and final version) and up  to *PowerShell (Core) 7.4.x*, you get NO control over what *kind* of `[datetime]` instances are constructed**, as reflected in their [`.Kind` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.Kind):

- In ***Windows PowerShell***, which requires a ***custom* date-string format** (e.g. `"\/Date(1633984531266)\/"`), you *invariably* get `Utc` instances.
- In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, which **additionally recognizes string values that are (variations of) ISO 8601 date-time strings** (e.g. `"2021-10-11T13:27:12.3318432-04:00"`), the `.Kind` value depends on the *specifics of the string value*:

  - If the string ends in `Z`, denoting UTC, you get a `Utc` instance.
  - If the string ends in a UTC *offset*, e.g. `-04:00` you get a `Local` instance (even if the offset value is `00:00`)

    - Note that this means that the timestamp is translated to the *caller*'s local time zone, so the original offset information is *lost* (unless the caller's time zone's offset happens to match).
  - Otherwise you get an `Unspecified` instance.

**Update:**

While *Windows PowerShell* will see no new features, in **PowerShell 7.5+**,<sup>[1]</sup> based on the feature request in [GitHub issue #13598](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13598), `ConvertFrom-Json` will have a **`-DateKind`** parameter, so as to allow explicitly requesting the date kind of interest, and to alternatively construct [`[datetimeoffset]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset) instances, which are generally superior to [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime).
In the absence of a `-DateKind` argument in a given call, the (PowerShell (Core)) behavior described above  will continue to apply.

---

**Workaround**:

- Note: In the event that you need access to the *raw string values*, exactly as defined, the solution below wont' work. You'll have to retrieve the raw JSON text and perform your own parsing, using [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and the response's `.Content` property, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) notes.

The following snippet **walks a `[pscustomobject]` graph, as returned from `Invoke-RestMethod`** and explicitly **converts any `[datetime]` instances encountered to `Local` instances *in place*** (`Unspecified` instances are treated as `Local`):

```
# Call Invoke-RestMethod to retrieve and parse a web service's JSON response.
$fromJson = Invoke-RestMethod ... 

# Convert any [datetime] instances in the object graph that aren't already 
# local dates (whose .Kind value isn't already 'Local') to local ones.
& {
  # Helper script block that walks the object graph.
  $sb = {
    foreach ($el in $args[0]) { # iterate over elements (if an array)
      foreach ($prop in $el.psobject.Properties) {
        # iterate over properties
        if ($dt = $prop.Value -as [datetime]) {
          switch ($dt.Kind) {
            'Utc' { $prop.Value = $dt.ToLocalTime() }
            # Note: calling .ToLocalTime() is not an option, because it interprets
            #       an 'Unspecified' [datetime] as UTC.
            'Unspecified' { $prop.Value = [datetime]::new($dt.Ticks, 'Local') }
          }
        }
        elseif ($prop.Value -is [Array] -or $prop.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) { 
          & $sb $prop.Value # recurse
        }
      }
    }
  }
  # Start walking.
  & $sb $args[0]
} $fromJson

# Output the transformed-in-place object graph
# that now contains only Local [datetime] instances.
$fromJson
```

---

<sup>[1] See [GitHub PR #20925](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/20925). It should first become available in PowerShell 7.5.0-preview.3, the next 7.5 *preview* version to be released as of this writing.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $requestHeaders

$changeddate = $response.fields.'System.ChangedDate'

$datetime  = ([DateTime]$changeddate).ToLocalTime()
```