# Filtering JSON by timestamp in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have retrieved json log data from a rest API as follows

```
[
  {
    "id": "6523276",
    "type": "logs",
    "attributes": {
        "created-at": "2022-02-22T10:50:26Z",
        "action": "delete",
        "resource-name": "DocumentABC.docx",
        "user-name": "Joe Smith"
        }
  },
  {
    "id": "6523275",
    "type": "logs",
    "attributes": {
        "created-at": "2022-02-22T10:03:22Z",
        "action": "create",
        "resource-name": "Document123.docx",
        "user-name": "Joe Smith"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "6523274",
    "type": "logs",
    "attributes": {
        "created-at": "2022-02-22T06:42:21Z",
        "action": "open",
        "resource-name": "123Document.docx",
        "user-name": "Joe Smith"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to Post the json to another web app but I only want the last hour of logs.
In the json example above, the current time was 2022-02-22T10:55:22Z, therefore I'm only interested in the first two log entries.

For example

```
[
  {
    "id": "6523276",
    "type": "logs",
    "attributes": {
        "created-at": "2022-02-22T10:50:26Z",
        "action": "delete",
        "resource-name": "DocumentABC.docx",
        "user-name": "Joe Smith"
        }
  },
  {
    "id": "6523275",
    "type": "logs",
    "attributes": {
        "created-at": "2022-02-22T10:03:22Z",
        "action": "create",
        "resource-name": "Document123.docx",
        "user-name": "Joe Smith"
    }
  }
]
```

Here is my powershell v7 script

```
$json = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$filterTime = (Get-date).AddHours(-1)
$RFCfilterTime = [Xml.XmlConvert]::ToString($filterTime,[Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode]::Utc)
$Filteredjson = $json | Where-Object $json.attributes[0] -ge $RFCfilterTimefilterDate  
$jsonToPost = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @($Filteredjson) -Depth 5
```

The problem is ConvertFrom-Json changes the 'created-at' from RFC3339 format to 'datetime' format.
Therefore the Where-Object filter doesn't work...

```
id                 type attributes
--                 ---- ----------
6523276            logs @{created-at=22/02/2022 10:50:26 AM; action…
6523275            logs @{created-at=22/02/2022 10:03:22 AM; action…
6523274            logs @{created-at=22/02/2022 6:42:21 AM; action=…
```

How do I change all of the 'created-at' objects back to RCF3339 format?

Is the
`$json | Where-Object $json.attributes[0] -ge $RFCfilterTimefilterDate`
statement being used correctly?

Is there any easier way altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach should work in principle, but there was a problem with your `Where-Object` statement - see the bottom section.
[Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223846/45375) shows how to work with the `[datetime]` instances that result from `ConvertTo-Json`'s parsing directly, but a bit more work is required:

- Indeed, **in *PowerShell (Core) v6+* [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)** (which with JSON web services is used *implicitly* by `Invoke-RestMethod`) **automatically deserializes ISO 8601-format date-time strings such as `"2022-02-22T10:03:22Z"` into `[datetime]` [`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instances**, and, conversely, on (re)serialization with [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json), `[datetime]` instances are (re)converted to ISO 8601 strings.
- While this enables convenient chronological comparisons with other `[datetime]` instances, such as returned by `Get-Date`, there is a major pitfall: **Only `[datetime]` instances that have the same `.Kind` property value compare meaningfully** (possible values are `Local`, `Utc`, and `Unspecified`, the latter being treated like `Local` in comparisons).
- Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.2.1, **you don't get to control what `.Kind` of `[datetime]` instances `Convert-FromJson` constructs - it is *implied* by the specific date-time string format of *each string*** recognized as an ISO 8601 date.

  - Similarly, on (re)*serialization* with `ConvertTo-Json`, the `.Kind` value determines the string format.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69532663/45375) for details.

In your case, because your date-time strings have the `Z` suffix denoting UTC, `[datetime]` instances with `.Kind` `Utc` are constructed.

Therefore, **you need to ensure that your comparison timestamp is a `Utc` `[datetime]` too**, which calling `.ToUniversalTime()` on the `Local` instance that `Get-Date` outputs ensures:

```
# Note the need for .ToUniversalTime()
$filterTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-1)
# Note: Only works as intended if all date-time strings are "Z"-suffixed
$filteredData = $data | Where-Object { $_.attributes.'created-at' -ge $filterTime }
```

However, at least hypothetically a given JSON document may contain *differing* date-time string formats that result in *different* `.Kind` values.

The way to handle this case - as well as the case where the string format is consistent, but not necessarily known ahead of time - you can **use the generally preferable `[datetimeoffset]` ([`System.DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset)) type**, which automatically recognizes timestamps as equivalent even if their expression (local vs. UTC) is different:

```
# Note the use of [datetimeoffset]
[datetimeoffset] $filterTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)
# With this approach the specific format of the date-time strings is irrelevant,
# as long as they're recognized as ISO 8601 strings.
$filteredData = $data | 
  Where-Object { [datetimeoffset] $_.attributes.'created-at' -ge $filterTime }
```

Note: Strictly speaking, it is sufficient for the *LHS* of the comparison to be of type `[datetimeoffset]` - a `[datetime]` RHS is then also handled correctly.

**Potential future improvements:**

- [GitHub issue #13598](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13598) proposes adding a `-DateTimeKind` parameter to `ConvertFrom-Json`, so as to allow explicitly requesting the kind of interest, and to alternatively construct `[datetimeoffset]` instances.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> Is the `$json | Where-Object $json.attributes[0] -ge $RFCfilterTimefilterDate`
> statement being used correctly?

No:

- You're using [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax) in which the LHS of the comparison (the `-Property` parameter) must be the name of a *single* (non-nested) property directly available on each input object.
- Because *nested* property access is required in your case, the regular *script-block*-based syntax (`{ ... }`) must be used, in which case the input object at hand must be referenced explicitly via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).
- `.attributes[0]` suggests you were trying to access the `created-at` property *by index*, which, however, isn't supported in PowerShell; you need to:

  - either: spell out the property's name, if known: `$_.attributes.'created-at'` - note the need to *quote* in this case, due to use of the nonstandard `-` char. in the name.
  - or: use the [intrinsic `.psobject` member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) that provides reflection information about any given object: `$_.attributes.psobject.Properties.Value[0]`

Thus, with spelling out the property name - and with making sure that the LHS `[datetime]` value is represented as an ISO 8601-formatted string too, via `.ToString('o')` - your statement should have been:

```
$json | Where-Object {
  $_.attributes.'created-at'.ToString('o') -ge $RFCfilterTimefilterDate 
}
```

Comment: Its true, there were more different date-time strings in the JSON that I needed to sort/filter. Thanks very much.

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped, @DanTracey; my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that newer version of `ConvertFrom-Json` implicitly parses timestamps as `[datetime]` is actually to your advantage - `[datetime]` values are *comparable*, so this simply means you can skip the step where you convert the threshold value to a string:

```
$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$filterTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)
$filteredData = $data | Where-Object {$_.attributes.'created-at' -ge $filterTime}
$jsonToPost = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @($filteredData) -Depth 5
```

Comment: In which PowerShell version did implicit datetime parsing begin? 6.x? 7.1?