# Using -like in Powershell with JSON Dates in -s (sortable) format - why am I forced to use 'American' format?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I've got my dates in a JSON file in sortable (-s). The first is:

```
"DTSlocal": "2012-11-10T08:09:35"
```

This is 10th November 2012 at 08:09:35 (local)

When I load the file and convert from JSON (new object = $data), PowerShell tells me the above sample value is now:

```
$data[0].DTSlocal
Saturday, 10 November 2012 8:09:35 AM
```

Ok, good.  But, to find ALL the data from this date I've tried:

```
$data | Where-Object -Property DTSlocal -LIKE '10/11/2012*'   #fails
$data | Where-Object -Property DTSlocal -LIKE '11/10/2012*'   #works (!)
```

My Culture values are correctly set for 'Australia', viz  d-MM-yyyy  etc

### Am I doing something wrong in having to search in 'American' format?

**Update 01:** Add example, as requested. Note: this is how I *was* trying it rather than using the subsequent suggestions. So others can learn what was going wrong.  I'll also try the suggestions and report back.

Sample data file '*tinySample.json*':

```json
[
  {
    "DTSorig": "2012-11-09T21:09:35.612Z",
    "DTSlocal": "2012-11-10T08:09:35",
    "Latitude": -39.9526772,
    "Longitude": 146.8924461,
    "Source": "WIFI",
    "Accuracy": 24
  },
  {
    "DTSorig": "2012-11-09T21:11:32.285Z",
    "DTSlocal": "2012-11-10T08:11:32",
    "Latitude": -36.8526774,
    "Longitude": 142.8924487,
    "Source": "WIFI",
    "Accuracy": 23
  }
 ]
```

Powershell testing:

```
$data = Get-Content .\tinySample.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# quick look at PS object's values:
$data

DTSorig   : 9/11/2012 9:09:35 PM
DTSlocal  : 10/11/2012 8:09:35 AM
Latitude  : -39.9526772
Longitude : 146.8924461
Source    : WIFI
Accuracy  : 24

DTSorig   : 9/11/2012 9:11:32 PM
DTSlocal  : 10/11/2012 8:11:32 AM
Latitude  : -36.8526774
Longitude : 142.8924487
Source    : WIFI
Accuracy  : 23

# Find values for 10th November 2012

$data | Where-Object -Property DTSlocal -LIKE '10/11/2012*'
#nothing

$data | Where-Object -Property DTSlocal -LIKE '11/10/2012*'
# same two values returned as per  $data (above)
```

Comment: please show a [mcve]. Did you use `ConvertFrom-Json`? And why do you match dates as strings instead of doing a proper comparison?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did use `ConvertFrom-Json`. I'm still fairly new to PowerShell, so what do you mean by 'proper comparison'?    I'm trying to learn how to search for all objects/records that have a date of  '2012-11' (i.e. all of November 2021) or those with '2012-11-10' etc.   FYI the source data is Google Takeout Location (JSON).

Comment: I mean the [`[datetime]` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) already has comparison operators so just compare it like `$data |% { $_.DTSlocal -eq [datetime]::new(2022, 6, 12)`. Anyway please make a [mcve] to make the question valid

Answer (score 1):

[`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* implicitly converts *string* JSON property values such as `"2012-11-10T08:09:35"` to `[datetime]` instances, so that is what your `-like` operation operates on - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69532663/45375) for more information on how `ConvertFrom-Json` parses dates, including how things work differently in *Windows PowerShell*.

- [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) is a *string* operator, which, as all PowerShell string operators do, ***implicitly stringifies* its LHS**, if it isn't already a string.
- **PowerShell typically stringifies in a culture-*invariant* manner**; specifically, it uses the so-called ***invariant culture***, `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` ([`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), which is a culture ***based* on the US English culture**, but distinct from it and guaranteed not to change over time.

  - It is these qualities - culture-independence, long-term stability - that make the invariant culture suitable for *programmatic processing*, whereas culture-*sensitive* representations not only depend on the runtime environment but are permitted to change over time.

    - *Argument-less* `.ToString()` calls on .NET types that support culture-sensitive representations *do* return such culture-dependent representations, which is why you should *not* rely on them in programmatic processing.
  - PowerShell requests use of this invariant culture from (non-string) objects by passing `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`, which implements the [`System.IFormatProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IFormatProvider) interface,  to the `System.IFormatProvider`-typed
    `provider` or `formatProvider` argument of one of the following, in order of precedence, *if available* (not all .NET types support culture-appropriate representations):

    - [`System.IFormattable.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IFormattable.tostring), if the target object's type supports the [`IFormattable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IFormattable) interface.
    - The target object's `.ToString` method, *if* it has an overload that accepts an `IFormatProvider` as the only parameter.

---

Since the **invariant culture** is based on the US English culture, it **uses a *month-first* format in short, numeric date representations**, such as when you stringify a `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) instance.

Applied to a simplified example:

```
[datetime] "2012-11-10T08:09:35" -like '11/10/2012*'
```

is implicitly the same as:

```
([System.IFormattable] [datetime] "2012-11-10T08:09:35").
  ToString(
   [NullString]::Value, 
   [System.IFormatProvider] [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
  )  -like '11/10/2012*'
```

which is implicitly the same as:

```
'11/10/2012 08:09:35' -like '11/10/2012*'
```

and therefore `$true`.

---

As [phuclv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995714/phuclv) points out, however, it's worth considering working with the properties and methods of the `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) type directly, instead of relying on *string* representations.

Answer (score 0):

.tostring() seems to do what you want vs the implied conversion.

```
set-culture en-au # then restart powershell


$a = get-date


"$a"

06/12/2022 13:19:46


$a.tostring()

12/06/2022 1:19:46 PM


$a.tostring() -like '12/06/2022*'

True


set-culture en-us
```

Comment: Yes, argument-less `.ToString()` calls on .NET types that support culture-sensitive representations _do_ return representations based on the _current culture_ - but that is precisely why you shouldn't use them:
not only is the result dependent on what the current culture is - and may therefore act differently on other machines - .NET cultures are permitted to change over time (although that happens only infrequently).
PowerShell's implicit use of the _invariant culture_ is something to embrace for programmatic processing with long-term stability.

Comment: Of course, it's even better to avoid working with _string representations_ of (non-string) data altogether, when possible.

Comment: Thank you again to those who have not only responded, but taken the time to explain - n some detail - specifically @mklement0   I'm not a developer but like to learn such things to solve problems like "I've got a huge Google Takeout Location Json export file. Where was I on 10th November 2012?  Or when did I visit Melbourne? "  I can use Geolocation APIs already, from an earlier photo-location exercise.