# Powershell DataContext variable set to false returns true

Tags: powershell, boolean, datacontext

I'm using a datacontext in my powershell app (a first for me) and from what I can tell all datacontext properties and values are set with JSON and all values are strings.  Example:

```
$DataObject =  ConvertFrom-Json @"

{
    "myproperty":"false"
}
```

But I'm having an issue where that false up there is not always evaluation to false.  When I bind a control's enable property to myproperty, it properly disables as it's set to false.

But if I try to evaluate that property as a bool, it returns true:

```
If($state.myproperty){$true} Else {$false}
True
```

I don't understand why it registers as a boolean false, for purposes of the control, but I cannot reference it as such in code.

Please school me on what I'm missing.

**EDIT** I've come to understand Powershell will register any string over 0 characters as true.  However, I'm still curious as to why when bound to a control property, this doesn't seem to be an issue.

**EDIT2** I worked around this by not actually setting a default value in the JSON and simply setting the $state.myproperty to $false near the beginning of the script and set it to $true when my condition required.

Again still curious as to why the control binding properly evaluates the string "false".  Also if I wanted to initialize this in JSON, can you do so without use of quotes?  E.g. "myproperty":false ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On the [JSON](https://json.org) side**:

- **`false` and `true` - note the absence of quoting - are  *Boolean* JSON values** that represent the values their names imply.
- By contrast, **`"false"` and `"true"` are JSON *strings*** whose value *happens to be* `false` and `true`, respectively - a string value has **no intrinsic meaning**, except *by convention* that the *consumer* of a JSON document must be aware of.

  - (An example of such a convention is that `ConvertTo-Json` and `ConvertFrom-Json` use specially formatted strings such as `"2022-06-27T15:31:38.935539-04:00"` to represent *date/time* (`[datetime]`) values, to compensate for the absence of a date/time data type in JSON itself - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69532663/45375))

Thus, you should use the following to create an object whose `.myproperty` value contains an actual Boolean value - note that `false` is *unquoted*:

```bash
$DataObject =  ConvertFrom-Json @"
{
    "myproperty": false
}
"@
```

Generally, aside from *strings*, which are always *double-quoted* (e.g., `"foo"`), **JSON supports the following *unquoted* primitive data types** as values:

- Booleans: `true` and `false`
- Null values: `null`
- Numbers: e.g., `42`, `-42`, `1.0` and `1e2`

  - Note: The [*standard*](https://json.org/) doesn't permit prefix `+` or `.1` as shorthand for `0.1`, and supports *decimal* number representations only; specific *implementations*, however, may be less strict.

**On the PowerShell / .NET side**:

PowerShell's [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) maps these values to their analogous .NET data types, `[string]` ([`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String)) and `[bool]` ([`System.Boolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Boolean)):

```bash
(' false ' | ConvertFrom-Json).GetType().FullName   # -> System.Boolean
# vs. 
(' "false" ' | ConvertFrom-Json).GetType().FullName # -> System.String
```

In terms of interpreting these values as Booleans, this means:

- Only *unquoted* `false` and `true` values map directly onto their `[bool]` counterparts (expressed as `$false` and `$true` in PowerShell).
- As you've observed, **when PowerShell evaluates a string *in a Boolean context*, it considers *any non-empty string `$true`, irrespective of its content***, so that `[bool] "false"` yields `$true` as well.

  - If you're dealing with string that you know to contain either `"true"` or `"false"` (or any case variation thereof) and you want to parse it *as a Boolean*, use the [`[bool]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Boolean.Parse) method; e.g., `[bool]::Parse("false")` yields `$false`, as intended.
- **PowerShell generally implements its own, automatic to-Boolean conversions**<sup>[1]</sup> (such as the one described above), which **do *not* apply to .NET APIs**.

  - Given that .NET has *no* built-in string-to-Boolean conversion, it is up to the `DataContext` type to interpret strings as Booleans, though the use of `[bool]::Parse()` is a logical candidate (in C# syntax, e.g.: `bool.Parse("false")`)

---

<sup>[1] For a summary of the conversion rules, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).</sup>